# Django: Generate list of strings

Tags: python, django

I have a function that I pass to the context in views.py and use in a django template for use in a javascript chart.

function:

```
def cleaning_data_plotly(area_id):
    _input = pricecleaning.values('percent_of_obs','price_cleaning',)
    data = []
    for row in _input:
        data.append(str("Price of cleaning is "  + str(row['price_cleaning']) + " USD in " + str(percent_of_obs)+" % of cases"))
return data
```

template:

```
text: {{ price_cleaning }},
```

When I inspect the output I see this:

```
text: [&#39;Price of cleaning is 68 USD in 3.58 % of cases &#39;, &#39;Price of cleaning is 78 USD in 7.58 % of cases &#39;],
```

Whereas I expected this:

```
text: ["Price of cleaning is 68 USD in 3.58 % of cases", "Price of cleaning is 78 USD in 7.58 % of cases"],
```

How do I get proper strings? Any help is much appreciated!

I'm using Python 3.5 and Django 1.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `| safe` if you don’t want to see the quotes escaped like that.

```
{{ price_cleaning | safe }}
```

[From the docs, the **`safe`** filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#safe)

> Marks a string as not requiring further HTML escaping prior to output. When autoescaping is off, this filter has no effect.